# Unix how do you block unix/linux `wall` messaging?

Tags: linux, unix

How do you block unix/linux `wall` messaging?

```
Example: 
SSH somemachine
WALL annoy the s*** out of people on machine
```

Desired goal: deny wall on owned machine

Comment: Could you simply uninstall the program? Or remove the executable flag on it?

Comment: I'm not root on the desired machine. I'm looking for a way to suppress if for nothing else can be done

Comment: If you aren't root on the machine, you aren't going to be able to do anything for anyone but yourself. Is that what you are asking for?

Comment: Yes I dont want other people who ssh into the machine using 'wall' and plaster my terminals

Comment: What does this question have to do with MySQL?

Comment: Typo from previous questions. My bad - fixed

Comment: @Gah_Jamn-it then the answer posted is what you are looking for with the `mseg` command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`mesg n`

From the man page

```
DESCRIPTION
   Mesg controls the access to your terminal by others.  It's typically used to allow or disallow other users to write to your terminal (see write(1)).
```

**Edit:**

This will *not* prevent `root` from sending wall messages

Comment: Alex - I dont care if root can message. Just other users

Comment: then `mesg n` should do it for you

Comment: Is there away to have it kick off in bashrc ?

Comment: I believe so, `.bashrc.`, `.bash_profile` or `.profile` will do

Answer (score 5):

Note that *every user* on the machine that does not want to see a `wall` message has to do `mesg n`.  Putting `mesg n` in `/etc/profile` might do that for all users.

Alternatively, if you only want `root` to be able to run `wall`, change its permission: `chmod 700 /usr/bin/wall`.

Answer (score 1):

The "mesg n" command shouldn't be run if you've sudo'd to another user, so it may be better to check whether the user owns the terminal, like:

```
test -O "`/usr/bin/tty`" && /usr/bin/mesg n
```

i.e., if the owner of the character special file output by "tty" is the effective user ID, run "mesg n".  I think this is safe for /etc/profile and its cousins.